# Bit shift OptionSet is multiples of 7? Swift 3

Tags: swift, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Bit shifted OptionSet...

```
struct VerifiedOptions : OptionSet {

    let rawValue: Int

    static let facebook = VerifiedOptions(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let email = VerifiedOptions(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let phoneNumber = VerifiedOptions(rawValue: 1 << 2)

    static let count:Int = 3
}
```

used like so...

```
    let options:VerifiedOptions = [.facebook,.email,.phoneNumber]

    for i in 0..<VerifiedOptions.count {

        let option = VerifiedOptions(rawValue: options.rawValue << i)

        print("O:",option.rawValue,"T:",options.rawValue)

        if options.contains(option) { print("match") }
    }
```

Prints resolve as

`O:7  T:7` `match` `O:14  T:7` `O:28  T:7`

Two questions....

1. Why is the bit shift in multiples of 7 and not multiples of 1?
2. Why isn't `options` showing as having all 3 options inside it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should use `for i in options.indicies {...`

Comment: Interesting, I'll looking into that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, caught it immediately

```
let option = VerifiedOptions(rawValue: options.rawValue << i)
```

Should be

```
let option = VerifiedOptions(rawValue: 1 << i)
```

Print out is

`O:1  T:7` `match` `O:2  T:7` `match` `O:4  T:7` `match`

1 + 2 + 4 = 7 = binary 111